# Creating a dictionary for each customer number in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, dataframe

I have the following data of customer interactions

```
customer  interacted  
c1           i1  
c1           i2  
c1           i1  
c2           i3  
c2           i1
```

I want to convert this data frame into another dataframe with one column as customer and the second column is a dictionary which stores the interaction history.

The second df should come like

```
customer   interhist

    c1     {'i1': 2, 'i2': 1}  
    c2     {'i3':1, 'i1':1}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `defaultdict` and `Counter` classes in the `collections` module are pretty useful for this type of problem. You could try something like the following:

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

data_map = defaultdict(Counter)
for line in your_data_source:
    customer, interacted = line.split()
    data_map[customer][interacted] += 1
```

This will give you a dictionary that maps customers to another dictionary, that maps their interactions to an integer.